# possible malware called FISE in Accessibility (Privacy & Security)

Tags: security, privacy, malware

I checked my Mac's security and privacy and noticed this entry FISE. When I click Show in Finder nothing happens. I've googled around and found no mention of it at all outside of spammy sites.

Before I unchecked this software it had "control my computer" access. I recently upgraded to Mojave, so it's possible this is an old program (this is on a 2012 Mac) which I had previously granted accessibility access to. However I don't recall doing so.

I did find one reputable mention of FISE, in a technical paper from 2010. I don't know if that is it. Given what the ["control my computer" permission enables](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/107306/what-does-security-privacy-accessibility-enable) I'm pretty concerned that its a form of mal/spyware.

Has anyone else has ever seen this program FISE on their mac?

EDIT - including screenshot of the FISE
[image: FISE-screenshot]

^ as mentioned when I click Show in Finder nothing happens

Comment: I googled and found this:
https://projects.eionet.europa.eu/fise-project/about/accessibility/
Is this helpful??

Comment: thank you, I googled and found that and one other white paper mention of FISE. I am not sure they are the same thing. I am trying to find out if anyone else has ever seen the program on their mac so that I can rule out if it is malicious or not

Comment: Could you show a screen shot of the fise? That will possible let me give you an answer how to tell for certain what’s up and not just googling other sites crowd sourcing program names “what is X” - those sometimes help, but we can be certain if you can get a little. Ore documentation edited into the question.

Comment: I have updated the question to include the screenshot, I should have done this at the outset thank you for asking for it

Comment: With "Show in Finder" not working, you can always search for it.  If Spotlight doesn't give you results, use the command line: `sudo find / -name FISE`

Comment: thank you for this tip. I did the above terminal command after granting it Full Disk Access to search as thoroughly as possible. Nothing showed up for FISE. Really makes me think its malware or spyware of some sort

Comment: I just found this same thing on my computer. I have a WACOM tablet set up and the accessibility was randomly disabled and It wouldn’t work. I had to plug in a mouse and go to the settings where I found that FISE app (that doesn’t have a unique icon). I immediately thought it must be malware. Did you ever figure out what it was?

Comment: Thanks for sharing this! I haven't yet found out what it is. Is it still on your computer? I've been using my Mac since 2014 so I honestly don't know how long its been on my machine. How long has it been there for you?

Comment: Since just that day! I unchecked its ability to control my computer and locked the settings and it has stayed dormant. I’d like to delete it, but I wasn’t sure what it was...

Comment: that's interesting, maybe it is a very recent unknown program. It is concerning that a program could put itself into that part of the mac, elsewhere it says accessibility enabled programs can control other software on the mac. Good move unchecking its ability to control computer.

Answer (score 1):

I found the same thing on my Mac and it seems it's and Android File Transfer app bundled with Wacom driver software for some reason https://www.reddit.com/r/wacom/comments/7m7pib/wacom_without_bloatware/